# Access model properties from relationship function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I had an accessor set on my Eloquent model that worked fine, but the associated database query was getting run once for every instance of the model I created. On my index page this meant 5 dozen queries.

```
<?php
class Thingy extends Model {
    protected $appends = ["parentType"];
    public function getParentTypeAttribute($value) {
        return self::where("type"=>$this->type, "parent"=>1)->value("name");
    }
}

class ThingyController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $thingys = Thingy::all();
        return view("things.index", compact("thingys"));
    }
}
```

<sup><sub>To explain briefly: there are two classes of "thingy" in the same database table, the class being indicated by a boolean value named "parent." I want to get the name of the parent when I access the child. I know this should be two tables but it's not.</sub></sup>

I wanted to reduce the number of database reads, so I tried changing it to a relationship instead. I figured this way I could take advantage of eager loading.

```
<?php
class Thingy extends Model {
    public function parent() {
        return $this->hasOne("Thingy", "id")->where("type"=>$this->type, "parent"=>1);
    }
}

class ThingyController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $thingys = Thingy::with(["parent"]);
        return view("things.index", compact("thingys"));
    }
}
```

The problem is that within the relationship method, `$this` is an empty instance of the model, unlike in the accessor, so `$this->type` is null.

Is there a way to access properties of the model I'm working with from within a relationship method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that out. Since I'm essentially doing a self-join on the same table, I can specify the "local" and "foreign" ID columns as the column I'm trying to match:

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->hasOne("Thingy", "type", "type")->where("parent"=>1);
}
```

I guess the key concept was to remember that I'm defining a relationship between two instances of the model, which is independent of the particular instances I'm dealing with.